# Find all combinations of two companies grouped by the projects they are tendering for

Tags: python, performance, time-limit-exceeded

I am working on the task to get all possible combinations (pairs) of ID's (companies) which participated in one bid and create a new data frame with ID_1, ID_2, matching parameter (tender ID).

I have prepared the following two functions which provide me with the required result however the execution time exceeds several hours when applying to df with more than 500k lines.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations
```

```
def get_pairs(dataframe, items):
   return (
       (c1, c2, item)
       for item in items
       for c1, c2 in combinations(dataframe[dataframe['tender_product'] == item]['ID_name'], 2)
   )
```

```
def get_all_pairs(df):
        pairs = get_pairs(df,df['tender_product'])
        df= pd.DataFrame(pairs, columns=['ID_name1', 'ID_name2','tender_product'])
        df=df.query('ID_name1 != ID_name2')
        df=df.drop_duplicates()
        df['pair'] = df['ID_name1'].astype(str)+'_'+df['ID_name2'].astype(str)
        df['reversed_pair'] =df['ID_name1'].astype(str)+'_'+df['ID_name2'].astype(str)
        return df
```

What are the options to optimize the code to make it work faster with the same result?

The sample of intial data:

| ID | tender_product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | tender_1 |
| 2 | tender_1 |
| 3 | tender_2 |
| 4 | tender_2 |

The sample of current output:

| ID1 | ID2 | tender_product | pair | reversed_pair |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | tender_1 | 1_2 | 2_1 |
| 3 | 4 | tender_2 | 3_4 | 4_3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the options to optimize the code

You wrote

```
       ...
       for item in items
       ... dataframe['tender_product'] == item ...
```

and complained that this takes a Long Time.
Even in the example data we can see that
the "find all rows containing item" scan
happens multiple times.
And then we discard duplicates.

What you wanted was to
[.groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
items. That lets you generate just the required rows
rather than generating tons of dups only to later drop them.

Comment: Thank you! First of all I've changed the items to df['tender_product'].unique() and series with IDs from grouped dataframe as advised. The execution time changed from several hours to 47 secs.